# How to support convert this regex from JAVA to C#?

Tags: java, c#, regex

I made an app in java that I now need to transfert to C# (UWP). I need to convert the following regex but C# does not support possessive qualifier so the "?+" part crashes the regex object. (the rest seemms to work fine)

Regex: `(?<!({0})(?:({1}))?)(?:({2}))?\b({3})(e?s|x)?\b(?:\s({4})[sx]?)?+(?!(\s{5}))`

The expression is dynamically built according to the user input.

```
Parts: 
 - {0}: exclude prefix 
 - {1}: include prefix
 - {2}: include prefix
 - {3}: include expression (is the word to find)
 - {4}: include suffix
 - {5}: exclude suffix
```

```
Logic: 
 - Find the word `{3}`.
 - Join the "include" prefix `{1}` & `{2}`, if presents, to the found
   word.
 - Join the "include" suffix `{4}`, if present, to the found word.
 - Don't match anything if the word (even if preceeded by the "include"
   prefix) is preceeded by the "exclude" prefix `{0}`.
 - Don't match anything if the word (even if followed by the "include"
   suffix) is followed by the "exclude" suffix `{5}`.
```

Concrete example: `(?<!({la})(?:({petite}))?)(?:({petite}))?\b({maison})(e?s|x)?\b(?:\s({bleu})[sx]?)?+(?!(\s{ciel}))`

```
Should match:
 - maison
 - petite maison
 - maison bleue
 - petite maison bleue

Should not match:
 - la maison
 - maison ciel
 - la petite maison
 - maison bleue ciel
 - la petite maison bleue
 - petite maison bleue ciel
 - la maison bleue ciel
 - la petite maison ciel
 - la maison ciel
 - la petite maison bleue ciel
```

The expression can be changed, if you have suggestions, but it needs to give the same result.

Note: I tried the `PCRE.NET Nuget` but it seems to create another issue with a lookbehind expression (lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 0).

So... Could anyone help me?

Comment: You may try Atomic groups [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) or [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/backtracking-in-regular-expressions#atomic-groups) which suppress the backtracking. For example, `(?>\\w+)(\\d\\d)(\\w+)` in C# works similar to `(\\w++)(\\d\\d)(\\w+)` in Java.

Comment: @SGKoishi Thank you, it seems to have worked! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an atomic group:

```
(?<!\bla\s+(?:petite\s+)?)(?:petite\s+)?(?>maison(?:e?s|x)?\b(?:\s+bleu[sxe]?)?)(?!\s+ciel)
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5Cbla%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3Apetite%5Cs%2B%29%3F%29%28%3F%3Apetite%5Cs%2B%29%3F%28%3F%3Emaison%28%3F%3Ae%3Fs%7Cx%29%3F%5Cb%28%3F%3A%5Cs%2Bbleu%5Bsxe%5D%3F%29%3F%29%28%3F!%5Cs%2Bciel%29&i=Should%20match%3A%0D%0A%20-%20maison%0D%0A%20-%20petite%20maison%0D%0A%20-%20maison%20bleue%0D%0A%20-%20petite%20maison%20bleue%0D%0A%0D%0AShould%20not%20match%3A%0D%0A%20-%20la%20maison%0D%0A%20-%20maison%20ciel%0D%0A%20-%20la%20petite%20maison%0D%0A%20-%20maison%20bleue%20ciel%0D%0A%20-%20la%20petite%20maison%20bleue%0D%0A%20-%20petite%20maison%20bleue%20ciel%0D%0A%20-%20la%20maison%20bleue%20ciel%0D%0A%20-%20la%20petite%20maison%20ciel%0D%0A%20-%20la%20maison%20ciel%0D%0A%20-%20la%20petite%20maison%20bleue%20ciel&o=m).

**Details**

- `(?<!\bla\s+(?:petite\s+)?)` - a location in string not immediately preceded with a whole word `la` (`\b` is a word boundary) followed with 1+ whitespaces and an optional sequence of `petite` and 1+ whitespaces
- `(?:petite\s+)?` - an optional `petite` and 1+ whitespaces sequence
- `(?>maison(?:e?s|x)?\b(?:\s+bleu[sxe]?)?)` - **here**, an **atomic group** that matches `maison`, then an optional sequence of an optional `e` followed with `s`  or an `x`, then a word boundary and then an optional sequence of 1+ whitespaces and `bleu` followed with 1 or 0 `s`, `x` or `e`
- `(?!\s+ciel)` - not followed with 1+ whitespaces and `ciel`.

See the C# demo:

```
var rx = @"(?<!\bla\s+(?:petite\s+)?)(?:petite\s+)?(?>maison(?:e?s|x)?\b(?:\s+bleu[sxe]?)?)(?!\s+ciel)";
var strings = new List<String> {" - maison"," - petite maison"," - maison bleue",
        " - petite maison bleue"," - la maison"," - maison ciel"," - la petite maison",
        " - maison bleue ciel"," - la petite maison bleue"," - petite maison bleue ciel",
        " - la maison bleue ciel"," - la petite maison ciel"," - la maison ciel"," - la petite maison bleue ciel"};
foreach (var s in strings)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} => \"{1}\"", s, Regex.Match(s, rx)?.Value);
}
```

Output:

```cs
 - maison => "maison"
 - petite maison => "petite maison"
 - maison bleue => "maison bleue"
 - petite maison bleue => "petite maison bleue"
 - la maison => ""
 - maison ciel => ""
 - la petite maison => ""
 - maison bleue ciel => ""
 - la petite maison bleue => ""
 - petite maison bleue ciel => ""
 - la maison bleue ciel => ""
 - la petite maison ciel => ""
 - la maison ciel => ""
 - la petite maison bleue ciel => ""
```